# What is the best way to store/read a large matrix in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 10000 items and I need to create a matrix of 10000 rows * 10000 columns. if I used one dimension array, then it would be huge.
Also, I want to set some values to a cell(i,j) where  0< i, j < 10000, so it would be a lot of iterations.

I could not come up with any idea.
So what is the best way to do it in node/javascript?

Comment: Could You describe what is the matrix used for, what operations You typically do with it and how often, what density the data have etc.?

Comment: @RomanHocke It is a rating-matrix of item based recommendation system. I was trying develop  such system by using movielens dataset with nearly 10000 movies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All examples will represent the following matrix, where `0` means no value:

```
| - - - - - - - |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| - - - - - - - |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| - - - - - - - |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| - - - - - - - |
| 5 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| - - - - - - - |
```

If you need all the cells in memory, so you need to keep a 2D array in the size of 10,000 x 10,000, I don't see a way around it.

Option 1 example (rows & cols are zero based):

```
var matrix = [[0,0,2,4],[1,0,0,3],[0,2,4,6],[5,0,2,0]];
```

If not, you can keep a one dimension array, with object that points to a given cell using `x` and `y` properties for example.

Option 2 example (rows & cols are 1 based for simplicity):

```
var matrix = [
    {x: 3, y: 1, value: 2},
    {x: 4, y: 1, value: 4},
    {x: 1, y: 2, value: 1},
    {x: 4, y: 2, value: 3},
    {x: 1, y: 3, value: 2},
    {x: 2, y: 3, value: 4},
    {x: 3, y: 3, value: 6},
    {x: 1, y: 4, value: 5},
    {x: 3, y: 4, value: 2}
];
```

If you need fast searching & access, you can use object, where the object properties names are for example the `row` index and each property value is an object that has `column` index as properties and their value is the cell value.
Note that object properties are strings that represents numbers, because numbers can not be used as properties names.

Option 3 example (rows & cols are 1 based for simplicity):

```
var matrix = {
    '1': {
        '3': 2,
        '4': 4
    },
    '2': {
        '1': 1,
        '4': 3
    },
    '3': {
        '2': 2
        '3': 4,
        '4': 6
    },
    '4': {
        '1': 5,
        '3': 2
    }
};

// Get value of cell (col: 3, row: 4)
console.log(matrix['4']['3']);
// Set value of cell (col: 2, row: 3)
matrix['3']['2'] = 100;

// Check if cell (col: 1, row: 1) has value
var hasValue = matrix['1'] !== undefined && matrix['1']['1'] !== undefined;
```

Comment: @alim add better examples

Comment: I opted to use one dimensional array which only stores half of the matrix since which is symmetric. I considered all these options, seems not very good way to it, so save memory should be better. thx :)